# azure active directory domain services unblock account

Tags: azure, entra-id, entra-domain-services

I am hoping that someone can help me unblock an account on an Azure VM.

The VM is domain joined and is running SQL Server 2014 on Windows Server 2016.  I have an office 365 / Azure AD tennant with Azure active directory domain services.

I have an account that is locked because of greater than 5 attempts, but if I give it some time, it goes active again.

```
net user /DOMAIN trent
...
Account active               Yes
Account expires              Never`

Password last set            5/26/2018 5:19:15 AM
Password expires             8/24/2018 5:19:15 AM
Password changeable          5/27/2018 5:19:15 AM
Password required            No
User may change password     Yes

Workstations allowed         All
Logon script
User profile
Home directory
Last logon                   5/26/2018 5:19:54 AM

Logon hours allowed          All

Local Group Memberships
Global Group memberships     *AdminAgents          *Domain Users
                             *AAD DC Administrators*PWS Wordpress Site Ad
The command completed successfully.
```

As soon as I go to login using RDP I am locked out.

I have looked up similar problems on like https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2125626-remote-desktop-services-causing-ad-account-lock-out and tried the tool at https://www.netwrix.com/account_lockout_examiner.html but it doesn't seem to want to connect to the AAD DS.

I have checked that there are:

- No mapped credentials
- No old cached creds
- No other applications
- No scheduled tasks

I am not sure how to change the group policy to stop it happening, I can't install AD DS because it is on AAD DS.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So it turned out that I had a LOB app on my PC that was trying to auth with my old creds which was creating the problem on RDP.

How I solved this was to track the login attempts, using a different admin user on the server using the script found here https://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/737-basic-domain-logon-tracking-script

This LOB app was not providing any indication of user fails, but as soon as I tried to login, it would indicate locked out.